# C# - Generic Types in Method Signature - Why CS1503, "Cannot Convert from IThing to ns.IThing"?

Tags: c#

While trying to work out an adapter pattern for use in an EFCore application with C# 9 under Visual Studio 2019, I'd developed a method something like the `HandleThing<IThing>(IThing otherThing)` method, below

```
namespace ns {
  public interface IThing
    {

    }

    public class Thing : IThing
    {
        public Thing(IThing thing)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ThingHandler
    {
        public void HandleThing<IThing>(IThing otherThing)
        {
            var entityThing = new Thing(otherThing);
        }
}
```

Subsequently, I'm presented with an error in the `HandleThing<IThing>` definition, at the 'otherThing' argument to the Thing constructor: "CS1503: Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'IThing' to 'ns.IThing'".

While VS recommends a cast such as the following, and that appears to work out at this point, I'm not certain I understand why this error is occurring, or why the cast would be needed.

```
    public class ThingHandler
    {
        public void HandleThing<IThing>(IThing otherThing)
        {
            var entityThing = new Thing((ns.IThing)otherThing);
        }
    }
```

Updating it to the following, it also eliminates a warning about nullability

```
    public class ThingHandler
    {
        public void HandleThing<IThing>(IThing otherThing)
            where IThing: notnull
        {
            var entityThing = new Thing((ns.IThing)otherThing);
        }
    }
```

It was my impression that the IThing type in the initial `HandleThing<IThing>(IThing otherThing)` signature would represent the IThing interface type that I'd already declared.

Is something getting lost across the generics in the definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the generic parameter was unconstrained.

Your *generic parameter* declaration `<IThing>` was a little skewed (which was likely confusing). Use `T`, and ***then*** constrain by `Ithing`

**What you had**

```
public void HandleThing<IThing>(IThing otherThing)
```

Instead, use standard `T` or `T` prefix so you don't get confused

```
public class ThingHandler
{
   public void HandleThing<T>(T otherThing) where T : IThing
   {
      var entityThing = new Thing(otherThing);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That had me sincerely stumped